# .NET Custom Threadpool with separate instances

Tags: c#, web-crawler, threadpool

What is the most recommended .NET custom threadpool that can have separate instances i.e more than one threadpool per application? 
I need an unlimited queue size (building a crawler), and need to run a separate threadpool in parallel for each site I am crawling.

Edit : 
I need to mine these sites for information as fast as possible, using a separate threadpool for each site would give me the ability to control the number of threads working on each site at any given time. (no more than 2-3)

Thanks
Roey

Comment: Why would you need to run a seperate threadpool for each site???

Comment: Take some time and watch this Daniel Moth's video: http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL26/. You will find that unlimited queue is not the road to unlimited performance.

Comment: I agree with Anthony. I don't think you need multiple thread pools. The thread pool is there to manage and balance work on the whole system. If you have multiple pools you'll just end up overloading your machine. don't forget there is an overhead to thread creation. This is what the thread pool is for - it carefully manages the number of threads to an optimal amount and divides the work amongst these threads.

Comment: I need a seperate threadpool for each site as not to use more than 2-3 crawling threads on each site. with the .NET threadpool there is no way to guarantee this (as all threads in the pool might be processing tasks from the same site at the same time.)

any alternatives to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8):

I believe [Smart Thread Pool](http://www.codeplex.com/smartthreadpool) can do this.  It's ThreadPool class is instantiated so you should be able to create and manage your separate site specific instances as you require.

Answer (score 3):

Ami bar wrote an excellent Smart thread pool that can be instantiated.

take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx)

Comment: +1 the answer was 2 min later. AdamRalphs' answer was prob not up yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Jon Skeet: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

[Parallel extensions for .Net (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) should actually work much better if you want a large number of parallel running tasks.

Comment: This is used for parallelizing to more than one CPU-core, however it doesn't solve my problem as the individual TaskManagers can't tell me when they've finished running all their tasks.

Comment: It's been a long time, so the links are dead (1st) or now point to a generic page (2nd). The TPL documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl. Indeed, it seems to use `System.Threading.ThreadPool` under the hood, which means that it only provides _one_ pool per application.

Answer (score 1):

Using BlockingCollection can be used as a queue for the threads.
Here is an implementation of it.
**Updated at 2018-04-23:**

```
public class WorkerPool<T> : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<T> queue = new BlockingCollection<T>();
    List<Task> taskList;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;
    int maxWorkers;
    private bool wasShutDown;

    int waitingUnits;

    public WorkerPool(CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken, int maxWorkers)
    {
        this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        this.maxWorkers = maxWorkers;
        this.taskList = new List<Task>();
    }
    public void enqueue(T value)
    {
        queue.Add(value);
        waitingUnits++;
    }
    //call to signal that there are no more item
    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        queue.CompleteAdding();          
    }

    //create workers and put then running
    public void startWorkers(Action<T> worker)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxWorkers; i++)
        {
            taskList.Add(new Task(() =>
            {
                string myname = "worker " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                try
                {
                    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {                     
                        var value = queue.Take();
                        waitingUnits--;
                        worker(value);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (ex is InvalidOperationException)  //throw when collection is closed with  CompleteAdding method. No pretty way to do this.
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }));
        }

        foreach (var task in taskList)
        {
            task.Start();
        }
    }

    //wait for all workers to be finish their jobs
    public void await()
    {
        while (waitingUnits >0 || !queue.IsAddingCompleted)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        shutdown();
    }

    private void shutdown()
    {
        wasShutDown = true;
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());            
    }

    //case something bad happen dismiss all pending work
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!wasShutDown)
        {
            queue.CompleteAdding();
            shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
WorkerPool<int> workerPool = new WorkerPool<int>(new CancellationTokenSource(), 5);

workerPool.startWorkers(value =>
{
    log.Debug(value);
});
//enqueue all the work
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    workerPool.enqueue(i);
}
//Signal no more work
workerPool.CompleteAdding();

//wait all pending work to finish
workerPool.await();
```

You can have as many polls has you like simply creating new WorkPool objects.

Answer (score 0):

This free nuget library here: [CodeFluentRuntimeClient](https://nuget.org/packages/CodeFluentRuntimeClient) has a CustomThreadPool class that you can reuse. It's very configurable, you can change pool threads priority, number, COM apartment state, even name (for debugging), and also culture.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a [Dataflow Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline). I added these later answer because i find Dataflows a much better approach for these kind of problem, the problem of having several thread pools. They provide a more flexible and structured approach and can easily scale vertically.

You can broke your code into one or more blocks, link then with Dataflows and let then the Dataflow engine allocate threads according to CPU and memory availability

I suggest to broke into 3 blocks, one for preparing the query to the site page , one access site page, and the last one to Analise the data. 
This way the slow block (get) may have more threads allocated to compensate.

Here how would look like the Dataflow setup:

```
var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true };

prepareBlock.LinkTo(get, linkOptions);
getBlock.LinkTo(analiseBlock, linkOptions);
```

Data will flow from `prepareBlock` to `getBlock` and then to `analiseBlock`.
The interfaces between blocks can be any class, just have to bee the same. See the full example on  [Dataflow Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-creating-a-dataflow-pipeline)

Using the Dataflow would be something like this:

```
 while ...{
    ...
    prepareBlock.Post(...); //to send data to the pipeline
 }
 prepareBlock.Complete(); //when done
 analiseBlock.Completion.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token); //to wait for all queues to empty or cancel
```